Establishing Chirality For a 4D Person?
The Ordians are 4-dimensional people with three legs and three arms spanning the sideways plane, with a vertical spine like ours holding their heads and shoulders above the ground and two eyes facing forward.
The idea of "left" vs. "right" doesn't make any sense to them; they can rotate their bodies to any arbitrary phase in the sideways plane without ever changing the direction in which they are facing.
Now, each individual Ordian can obviously tell the difference between all of their three arms, and use whichever one they want at a given time. And they probably have internal chirality, just like we do: there's no need for all of their organs to be arranged with radial symmetry. But when trying to communicate with others, where the disposition of internal organs isn't immediately apparent, how could they establish egocentric directions? I.e., how would an Ordian be able to communicate the equivalent of "to my left", meaning "in the direction of a particular one of my limbs which you can identify by name"?

What do you mean by "eyes facing forward?" Our own eyes, facing forward, while comprehending our 3D world are nevertheless "looking" (simplistically) along a 1D line. Thus, no matter the direction we're facing inour 3D world, our perspective of left/right is referenced first by the 1D line of sight. So, what does "facing forward" mean? Because if both eyes are looking along the same line and/or plane, there's always a left/right/up/down. (Disclaimer: imagining what life in a 4D world is like is a bit beyond me.)

@JBH The same thing it means for us: the eyes are pointing along roughly parallel lines in the direction in which it is most natural for a person to walk. This is perpendicular to the spine, with which it forms the forward-vertical plane. For us, there is a unique axis perpendicular to that plane, the left-right sideways line, and features on one side of the plane cannot be rotated to the other side--they are chiral. In the Ordians' 4D world, there is no unique perpendicular axis--there are 2 leftover dimensions...

...so there are infinite possible axes contained in the sideways plane, any of which can be rotated into any of the others

The "sideways plane" for your creatures is 3D, instead of 2D for us, so they need more than 3 of each kind of limbs to operate stuff in 4D.

Presumably they have 4 dimensional eyeballs (hyperballs?) and brains. What's with the implicit supposition that they wouldn't be adapted to navigating 4 dimensional space?

@Vesper We don't have a "sideways plane". There's front/back, up/down, and then only a single axis left over--not a plane. Our sideways is spanned by two points, theirs by three.

@Escapeddentalpatient. There is no such supposition. The problem is not with navigating 4D space, it is with unambiguously identifying egocentric directions. You can navigate just fine with geocentric directions, and some human cultures don't use egocentric directioons at all.

This essentially reduces down to the same problem as "I am an astronaut on a spacewalk, how do I identify directions (without making reference to where my head is, only the direction I'm looking)", correct? (The current answers get lost in the sauce of 4d, but since the vertical axis is fixed, we can essentially ignore it.)

FYI https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/50142/79374 there are no stable orbits in 4D, so gravity has to work differently in your universe (such as by having gravity be independent of one of the four spatial dimensions).

@RobWatts I am well aware. Ordian physics is not our physics, and their world does not exist in a solar system.

@Kaia Kinda. It's not "how do I identify directions", it's "how do I define directions in a way that can be communicated to other people".

In golf, to unambiguously say if a ball is hooking or slicing, you can't just look at its spin and forward motion and gravity, you have to look at the handedness of the person that hit it.  So beware of those kinds of properties as well.

This isn't a problem of 4D versus 3D, this is a problem of rotational versus bilateral. How would a starfish solve this problem?

@No Name, please write that up as an answer - as someone with an interest  in such things, I'm kicking myself I didn't see it.

In 4D, there is chirality exactly like in 3D. Yes, in 4D, you can rotate a 3D left shoe into a 3D right shoe, but you can not do that to a 4D left shoe.

This is in the VTC queue, but I'm having trouble with "why?" Folks, just because you can't understand the question doesn't mean it's meant to be closed. I can't even wrap my head around what Logan's asking for and so I don't think there's an objective answer (by definition there isn't since no one can comprehend a 4D experience), but that doesn't mean someone couldn't come up with a good worldbuilding explanation. From the perspective of the rules, I don't see a problem with the question.

Reducing the problem
Since up/down is set by the direction of gravity, we don't really have to worry about it; if an Ordian needs to look upwards 20deg, that's the same as on Earth. So the challenge is 3D, not 4D, which is good news for us 3D creatures. (If you've played 4d Golf you're familiar with how playing golf along flat ground in 4D is the same as putting in 3d with no gravity.)
The 4D horizon is a 3D sphere, the same way the 3D horizon is a 2D circle. Ordians have a "forwards" based on where they're looking, but they're radially symmetric along the other axis. So you might think of the problem as equivalent to situations like:

Two astronauts can each see the direction the other is looking but not which way the other is oriented head/toe-wise (e.g. they're too far to see each other in detail, but they have laser pointers they can use to gesture with). How can they both orient themselves with the same "up"?
Somebody gave me a globe with no latitude/longitude lines, but it does have countries labelled. Over the phone, how can tell me what direction is north, or tell me how to rotate the globe to find any particular country?
I'm looking for Jupiter using a star chart, but I don't know which direction is north or what time it is.

Solutions
Alice and Bob are Ordians. She can see where Bob is looking, and where Bob is in relation to her, but not what Bob's internal sense of ana/kata/left/right is. She also knows Bob can look at her and at the direction she's looking.
"With me at 12-o'clock,"
Bob can keep facing forwards, but spin clockwise/anticlockwise in such a way that Alice is "12-o'clock" of him, and then use her to define the rest of the directions.
If Alice isn't visible, she can choose whatever other object to specify 12-o'clock, and if it isn't clear which way Bob is facing, she can pick two objects. E.g. if Alice is giving Bob directions, she might say "Alright, looking at the bank, with 12'oclock as the grocery store, now turn 90deg towards 5'oclock."
This is how we tend to learn the constellations, which is probably the closest we come to dealing with this problem regularly. To find Polaris, I find the Big Dipper and then I look in the direction pointed by the last two stars of the dipper.
"That way"
If you're trying to get somebody to look somewhere, or move in a certain direction, it's likely sufficient to point. If you need to point and indicate a 12-o'clock, you can point and then move your hand up and down to indicate an orientation.
Customary directions
We end up defining all kinds of 'customary' directions in day-to-day life. "3 blocks downtown of...", "windward", "downhill", and "towards the chemistry building" are all relative directions that, in a particular context, specify an absolute coordinate system. If you exist on more than a featureless void, there's likely tons of ways to establish a shared direction.

(Kinda funny to me that Ender's Game had the whole "enemy's gate is down" thing, but iirc doesn't deal with left/right/forward/backwards at all, it's just assumed that they all have those shared directions.)

Once you know "the enemy's gate is down", then your other directions become polar.  Clockwise/Counter-clockwise, and wallwards/centrewards — but you've pretty much reduced the remaining issue to a 2D-plane at that point

More like it's assumed they're all facing the gate, because the point of the exercise was to ambush the enemy

Just because there's an extra dimension in the Ordians' spacetime doesn't mean that they can have no concept of relative directions and rotations.
Here on Earth, in 3 dimensions, we can have North, South, East, West, Up and Down, which are relative to Earth, or Forward, Backward, Left, Right, Up and Down, which are (mostly) relative to a person.  We can also have one axis of rotation, for which we also have words: pitch (rotation around the left-right axis), yaw (rotation around the vertical axis) and so-on.
In 4 dimensions, we have the usual 3 spatial dimensions (x, y, z) plus one more: w.  This gives 8 directions at 90° to one-another rather than the 6 we have.  In four dimensions, it is also possible to have two completely independent axes of rotation.
So, Ordians are going to be able to define a vertical axis (say, ±z) and a direction at right-angles to that, from one shoulder to the other (call it ±w).
It's hard for a mere 3D creature like myself to say what the language of a 4D creature would be like, but it's highly likely that they'll have words for '+w' and '-w', as well as all the other possible cardinal directions and rotations.
The real difficulty for us comes with imagining them all and putting names to them.

Yes, they can have relative directions; that's not at issue. Like I said, they would have trouble distinguishing their own limbs. But when the sideways axis is not unique, because there's a whole sideways plane, how do you pick out a unique axis to communicate a relative direction to someone else? It's not a question of perception or language, but of geometry and body design.

In 3D, I can pick out a unique direction by specifying either the positive or negative of the cross-product of the sagital plane spanning vectors, and then call that "left" or "right"--but cross products don't exist in 4D, so can the Ordians do something similar, or not?

@LoganR.Kearsley Cross products are not necessary, even in 3D, if I understand the math correctly.  Have a look at https://marctenbosch.com/quaternions/... the math is a bit over my head, but the guy is writing a 4D computer game, and wrote this article as a result, so he must know something...

@MontyWild Since around the 17th Century, a measurement in the w direction has been referred to as "spissitude" (to go with "longitude" in the x direction, "latitude* in the y direction, and "altitude" in the z direction); and since 1904 the terms for "+w" and "-w" have been "ana" and "kata" (to go with "left"/"right"; "forwards"/"backwards"; and "up"/"down")

@LoganR.Kearsley A 2-dimensional being might believe that you have trouble distinguishing your own limbs, because "clockwise" and "counter-clockwise" seem to swap depending on whether you are face-down or face-up.  But, how much difficulty to you actually have with that?

@Chronocidal You are missing the point. Of course I jave no trouble distinguishing the sides of my own body. Neither would they. But enuring that you know what I mean when I say "on my left" is a completely different proposition.

@MontyWild He does indeed know something, and I am quite familiar with the mathematics of quaternions and rotors, but so far as I know his exceedingly overdue videogame never requires identifying the 4D analogs of "left" and "right" to another player.

@LoganR.Kearsley Okay, quick question: how would you explain — over radio, to an alien whose location you do not know — what "left" and "right" are?  If you can answer that, you'll be one step closer to figuring out your answer.  Besides, you appear to be labouring under quite a worrying misapprehension: the idea that "left" and "right" are determined by limbs, rather than the names for the limbs being determined by directions.  They may just use gauge directions rather than chiral directions, with are independent of their current chirality.

@Logan R. Kearsley And the 2-dimensional being will have just as much trouble trying to understand how your fellow 3-dimensional beings are able to understand what you mean when you tell them "on my left".  You appear to be inventing issues where they need not exist.

@Chronicidal If I had to describe it to an alien who could not see me, I'd use the chirality of beta decay of Cobalt-60. But that's not the situation at hand--Ordians can see each other. You seem to be distracted by the irrelevant of "names"; it doesn't matter whether the limbs or the directions are named first, what matters is being able to define the directions, which we can do because we have a unique axis perpendicular to the sagital plane.

2D creatures may have trouble understanding how we establish chirality when we can rotate out of their plane, but if they understand math, I can describe to them the mathematics of cross products and how we fix two objective reference axes, depending on whether they are Flatlanders or from the Planiverse. And if it is in fact impossible to establish a similar convention, and they must use guage directions (as some human cultures do), then that is an answer!

@LoganR.Kearsley You're using examples that rely on having already established mathematical conventions; using your Cross Product example, it relies on the fact that we've determined that one particular set of axis directions are "positive", and the other are "negative". Your Cobalt beta-decay example ignores that the very first step (and the hardest step) of the Wu Experiment was ensuring that the majority of the Cobalt atoms had the same direction of spin — and the alien doesn't know which direction of spin you're calling "clockwise" / "counter-clockwise". Some things require demonstration

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

“In four dimensions, it is also possible to have two completely independent axes of rotation.” — Not really. There are 3 rotations in 3D; in 4D, there are 5. What you mean, perhaps, is that the orientation is defined by a bivector in Euclidean 4D space, not a simple vector.

@kkmmistrustsSE Yes, really. There are 6 4D rotations, not 5. Rotations are defined in planes, and 4D gives you 2 fully perpendicular planes.

@LoganR.Kearsley Yes, 6 indeed, sorry. And, tangentially, no bounded gravity (in the sense $F \sim r^{-3}$) orbits, and no knots. The latter won't make your shoes fall off, but the former needs to be somehow taken care of. :)

@kkmmistrustsSE you can't have knots in lines, but you can have knots in sheets. Mathematical 4D knots are topological spheres, rather than topological circles. As for the behavior of gravity, that's a real issue in 4D worldbuilding, but dealt with elsewhere, and not relevant here.

@LoganR.Kearsley Mathematical topological knots are topological knots in the usual sense, but I won't argue otherwise. Chronocidal is absolutely correct, understanding his argument as mathematicians commonly understand each other, but you have your own interpretation of higher-D spaces, and are using your own terminology, unfamiliar to me. No wonder yous arguments couldn't converge, as yall don't speak the same language. I think you should agree that there's no point arguing when we speak different languages. I wanted to avoid this point, sorry, but if you insist so, here's how I see it.

Break their symmetry
The reason why we can look at a 3D person and immediately tell which of their sides is left, is that people cannot physically mirror themselves. With rotational symmetry, this doesn't work, because turning is possible. You can't tell if the 4D person you are looking at turned 120 degrees one way or the other just before you looked. You're just out of luck.
However, if they wear a red ribbon on one of their hands by custom, they can say "on my red side" and you will know. I think you can then extrapolate which side is "green" and which is "blue" without any more ribbons.
Change the paradigm
If you don't want to force any ribbons on them, just let them point directions relative to the surroundings rather than themselves. Sailors say "port" and "starboard" relative to their ship, no matter which way they face. Outside, you can say "east", "west", etc. Indoors, maybe some feng-shui based terms? I think it is reasonable they would develop a system like this when the first option is not naturally available.

You can add another coordinate name
Left and right in 3 space implies the x+ and x-. It could be any of the axes, but assume x for simplicity. Stretching your arms out would overlay them with the x axis. Now, if you raise them up, you imply an x component and a z+ component.
Your answer describes a hyper surface orthogonal to z. So on that plane (which to our 3d minds is an infinite cube), you would have to introduce another variable, let's call it j. The hyper surface would then vary along the x, y, and j axes. Their vernacular would create names for each: x is left and right, y is backwards and forwards, and j we'll make it up. Say weewards and wonwards. (Z is still up and down).
If the beings are four dimensional, I will assume that any description of direction will not be a single line which can be described by 2 points. In our 3d example being the origin, which is in this case your chest, and lets simplify your outstretched arm to a single point around your hand. Rather, it would be a surface in 4space. To describe a surface you need 3 points.
So your species would describe their surface "arms" in 4 space with their "chests" as the origin, but with the added j axis: left-weewards, left-wonwards, right-weewards, and right-wonwards.

OK, now how do you ensure that someone else knows which way is your "left-weewards" as opposed "left-wonwards". Naming the axes is trivial. Defining what they mean in an unambiguous way that can be understood by someone in any relative orientation is hard.

@LoganR.Kearsley by convention. When I say forwards, you assume it's where my eyes are pointing. From there you assume my left and right are orthogonal to forwards on the same plane.  The same with the j axis. If your species has a convention for body part alignment and at least one reference, the meaning would be understood

So what is the convention? There are four directions orthogonal to forward in the same plane, and there is no reason any two individuals should be aligned in any given way when facing each other. So how does the person you are talking to know that when you say "weewards" it means "the direction that this arm points in" as opposed to "the direction that this other arm points in?"

This isn't a problem of 4D versus 3D, this is a problem of rotational versus bilateral.
Consider the humble starfish: They have no left or right or front or back, all their arms are identical. They have an up and down, perpendicular to the plane of left/front/right/back, but this doesn't help them figure out which one is which. Nor do they need to: Instead of "front" they have "forward", the direction they happen to be going, and everything else is defined in relation to that. If they are not moving, then there simply is no forward
Your Ordians are similar: the have no left or right or ana or kata (some traditional terms for the directions of the fourth dimension), but they do have an up and down. Complicating matters, they also have a front and back, and prefer to orient themselves so that their front is facing forward, just like we do (this is where you found the rub, I presume?). But the solution is the same: Instead of "left" (say) they have "pointward", the direction they happen to pointing in, and everything else is defined in relation to that. If they are not pointing, then there simply is no pointward.
Yes, this is more arbitrary, but so is chirality in general. The left/right axis is the hardest to define, and is done so solely in relation to the other two axes. Throw in ana/kata, and you're going to have to designate a third laterality or live with the fact that you can't tell left from ana.
Because your Ordians are rotationally symmetric in the left/ana/right/kata plane, they do not have a designated left side. They might have a strong side, like most humans do, but which one it is cannot be distinguished as anything other than "the strong side", and it would be pointless to try because, again, they are rotationally symmetric in the relevant plane.
But if you absolutely, positively, must insist: call them "right", "left" and "other left". At least now you can say "no, your other left" and mean it.

@EscapedDentalPatient You know, I think I will

They need to know left from right!
The Ordians have stars, they have golf, and they have guns.  At least I imagine they do.  If two Ordians are staring downrange at the hated Hordians, and one is shooting off to one side, the other had better be able to tell him to aim a little further left, and mean it.
So as they look out, their three-dimensional retinas are arranged with a fovea at the center.  When they look out at the horizon, things above the horizon appear a little further down on the retina.  Things to the left appear a little to the right.  Things to the kata appear a little to the ana.  And all the opposite relations are true also.
So if Mama holds a light off to the kata, and it lands on the retina a little ana, Baby says "kata" and Mommy is very proud, because one day he is going to be standing in a nest of smashed Hordian eggs taking selfies.  But Baby will need to know kata is still kata even if he rotates, just as we need to know that up is still up even if we lie down on a bed.
Now does this have an anatomical correlate?  It's not guaranteed.  They could be "radiates" where left, right, ana, kata on their bodies are all exactly identical.  Even so, they will need to know at any given time which direction is kata, just as a cave diver wants to know which direction is up.  Kata is in a specific, fixed direction relative to up and forward, after all.
It is also conceivable that some phenomenon, such as magnetism or a gas giant in the sky, makes the directions more distinguishable, and biology has adapted to make one side, say, a bit more insulated that faces away from the gas giant.  Then the people who live on the kata of the gas giant call that side their kata side, and the people who live on the ana of the gas giant call that their ana side.  But it's the same side, just a regional difference in orientation.

They do indeed have stars (which follow complex helical paths through the 3D sky), though I hadn't gotten as far as determining if they have a game comparable to golf! There is, however, a lovely video game of 4D golf in our own universe. :)

They communicate directions relative to their face, not their arms.
The face is visible, well-defined, and a natural point of perspective for the individual in question. Humanoids can't rotate our heads far relative to our bodies, but if we could, I imagine we'd either have a similar convention or untwist our necks for clarity when referencing directions. Your creatures' rotationally symmetric body plan makes it even simpler; there's no conflicting information.
If they need to reference their hands specifically, not a point in space, they probably have a unique word for each arm relative to their organs. If someone absolutely needs to know which internally-referenced hand corresponds to one of the limbs they can see, they can wave it and say "this one"—outside of immediate spatial proximity, how often do we really need to specify one of our hands except in the context of dominance, injury, or another property not intrinsic to chirality?
I only question why they have two eyes instead of three for depth perception in all four dimensions.

Because all they need is two. Their retinas will be three dimensional, to capture the three dimensional "surface" of the objects they see, but to get the fourth dimension, they only need two eyes to stereoscope.

…Why the downvote?

Wasn't me. I was just answering your question about the eyes

I can't explain the downvote, either, so have an upvote to cancel it out!

There have been a few good answers now; the accepted one shares a key insight that helped me get my head around the issue in discussions in other forums--that there is, in fact a non-confusing way to approach the issue from one dimension down!
However, having had another week to think over how this ends up applying to the Ordians as described, I think it's worth sharing greater detail on how I have resolved the issue for these creatures in my own mind.
There is no reason for Ordian vertebrates to not be radially symmetric in the sideways plane at any particular vertebral position, and thus the Ordians are so symmetric. As explained in No Name's answer, they are thus in a similar position as a starfish, or other Earthling radiata; they have no distinguishable right or left side (ignoring the off-center madreporite in actual starfish, anyway), but given a distinct up-down axis is it is possible to define an egocentric sense of clockwise/anticlockwise rotation, which merely requires a sign convention for which name goes with which direction. Upon imposing a direction of travel, this is directly extensible to the idea of turning left or right--but that's where the dimensional analogy fails us. "Forwards" for an Ordian is just as perpendicular to the sideways plane as "upward" is--so it seems that they can establish an externally-observable egocentric sense of sideways rotation but not an externally-observable egocentric sense of yawing--that is, rotating the forward axis towards the side. With the extra degree of freedom, these concepts end up disconnected, and it remains impossible to, e.g., give unambiguous road directions in terms of left/right/ana/kata turns!
That's actually kind of a fun situation to explore--they can have some egocentric directions, but not to the extent that we Spacelanders do, and so they must be more reliant on explicit pointing or geocentric directions.
However, it turns out that the Ordians as described in the question do have a source of radial asymmetry, analogous to the starfish's posession of an off-center madreporite. While they are sideways-radially symmetric at any given position along the spinal axis, they only have two eyes, which results in broken symmetry when you pair up the eye-separation axis with the planar arrangement of the limb girdle. (Why do they have two eyes? Because they only need two, and complex eyes are biologically expensive; any simple symmetrical third eye that their ancient evolutionary ancestors may have had will have expeperienced strong selective pressure to disappear as the sophistication of each individual eye increased--even stronger than what would be experienced by a radially-symmetric Spacelander, as 4D eyes are more complex organs than 3D ones.)
So supposing we pick, without loss of generality, the spinal axis for defining an upper vs. lower viewpoint on the limb planes, and thus allowing us to establish a convention for egocentric descriptions of rotation. If we have some means of breaking the symmetry, and distinguishing one limb from the others, then we can label the remaining two limbs, and their associated directions, in terms of the direction in which they are rotated away from the distinguished limb. I don't want to introduce an artificial asymmetry (say, by giving them a strong hand that's obviously larger than the others) just for the sake of making them and their environment easier to describe, but the eyes do it for us: it would be possible to unambiguously associate each eye with one limb (just as we can associate our left eye with our left arm and left leg, etc.), based on their geometric relationships in a relaxed standard anatomic position, leaving the third limb unpaired. This, then, is our reference point which allows converting an externally-observable sense of egocentric rotation into an externally-observable egocentric definition of linear directions! Ordians can thus refer to "the eyeless direction", "the clockwise direction", and "the anticlockwise direction" in the same way that we can refer to left and right. Their situation is stilol not quite as convenient as ours, though; their phase in relation to anyone or anything else that they are facing is completely unrestrained, so it is still useless to give road directions in egocentric terms, as which branch of a fork in the road happens to align with which egocentric direction on any given approach is entirely random! (For similar reasons, there is no way for an Ordian to define the "left lane" vs. the "right lane" of a road, so there's no way to establish the equivalent of a "drive on the right" or "drive on the left" convention; Ordian road markings will have to be much more detailed than ours!)
After thinking of how fun it would be to be forced to deal with a lack of egocentric directions, though, it is kind of disappointing to realize that the Ordians can have them after all. So, I may just have to go ahead with an alternative design for the Ordian people and declare that there are, in fact, two sophont species on their world--the more directly human-analogous, mostly-trilaterally-symmetric Ordians already described here, and a centauroid species with 4 disphenoidally-arranged feet and only 2 arms and hands. For those people, it would be possible to define a left/right axis and an ana/kata axis, but not to establish any consistent sign convention for which way is left vs. right or ana vs kata!

3-D creatures cannot see 4-D creatures, only their "imprint" on three dimensions.
Your aliens just show us what they want us to see. And to keep themselves away from the uncanny valley, they show us something closely related to humans.
To better illustrate this, think of 2-D creatures we are visiting. They live in a sheet of paper, for simplicity.
If you are looking at the paper without touching it, the 2-D creatures cannot perceive you. They only have X and Y axis, and cannot perceive or interact with the Z axis.
When you poke the sheet with your fingertip, they see a fingerprint on their paper-world. To them, you are the fingerprint. But you can poke the sheet with another finger, the side of your hand, your tongue, or anything, really.
(Just don't make it weird and use the wrong body part).
The 2-D creatures might even think you are several different creatures, because they can only recognize the part you are showing.
You could even move through their plane and show you the cross-section of your ankle.
So to the circlians, who are very round, we show them the tip of our pinkie, which closely resembles a circle.
To the half-moonians, we poke the 2-D plane with a fingernail, which is somewhat moon-shaped and narrow.
The 4-D aliens find whatever body part they have that resembles a human the closest, and that is what they put in our 3-D space. The rest of their bodies is safely out of our view.
